# How to accept a Github repository invitation through API?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, github-api

I was looking at the Github API and it allows you to fetch all repository invites through an API endpoint (see https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/invitations/#list-invitations-for-a-repository). This works fine like this:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
login = 'xxx'
password = 'yyy'
url = 'https://api.github.com/user/repository_invitations'
repository_invites = requests.get(
            url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(login, password)).json()
print('response: ' + str(repository_invites))
```

I can then get out each request its `url` like this:

```
for repository_invite in repository_invites:
    print('url: ' + repository_invite.get('url'))
```

Which gives something back like:

```
url: https://api.github.com/user/repository_invitations/123456789
```

Github also mentions that you can accept an invite at https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/invitations/#accept-a-repository-invitation which mentions

> PATCH /user/repository_invitations/:invitation_id

What I don't get is how I can tell Github how to accept it though. This endpoint seems to be used for both deleting and accepting an invitation. Github talks about `PATCH` at https://developer.github.com/v3/#http-verbs which mentions you can use either a `POST` or send a `PATCH` request, however not how. So the question is, how do I know what I should send in the `PATCH` call? I tried this for example:

```
result = requests.patch(repository_invite.get('url'), json.dumps({'accept': True}))
    print('result: ' + str(result.json()))
```

Which gives back:

```
result: {'message': 'Invalid request.\n\n"accept" is not a permitted key.', 'documentation_url': 'https://developer.github.com/v3'}
```

Comment: I get a similar error here with either X is not a permitted key or if no body then For 'links/1/schema', [] is not a null or object.    -- are you sure it was just the auth issue? I'm fine cancelling the invitation using same approach with delete instead of patch so not convinced the auth its the problem. Any help appreciated.

Comment: tl;dr: send a PATCH *without a body* (but with correct credentials in headers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to call the API endpoint you will need to have authentication with your Github user and you need to send a `Patch` call (which can take data/headers if you would need them). Here's a working sample:

```
for repository_invite in repository_invites:
    repository_id = repository_invite.get('id')
    accept_invite = requests.patch('https://api.github.com/user/repository_invitations/'+ str(repository_id), 
            data={}, headers={},
            auth=HTTPBasicAuth(github_username, github_password))
```

Without the authentication the `Patch` call will give back a 404 response code because it is only accessible behind a login for obvious safety purpose. If you call the endpoint `user/repository_invitations/` followed by the ID Github will automatically accept the invitation.

Comment: Only extra thing I'll add here is that if you are authenticating using a personal access token, it must be granted `repo:invite` to be able to accept the invitation on behalf of a user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it with gh cli:

```bash
gh api user/repository_invitations | jq .[].id | each "p `gh api --method=PATCH user/repository_invitations/#{it}`"
```

It lists all the invitations, fetch the invitation ids and for each invitation id it makes a request to accept the invitation